# how i resolve this "the underlying provider failed on open" in Asp .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i do new window. when i open my projects then they are not connected to database every project give me different problem and error and this is not connect to database.

one project in which i use model first approach it show different exceptions.
"unable to connect SQL server ........"

and other in which i use DB first approach it give me error "the underlying provider failed to open"

[this excpetion is second in which i use DB first Approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vShKi.png)

Comment: it seems that there is problem with your connection string.

Comment: plz join me on skype i send u pic of this.

Comment: mr.zeeshan12@outlook.com

Comment: ohh..can you share your connection string

Comment: it would be helpful if you can share the connection strings. You can ofcourse mask the sensitive information.

Comment: <add name="FiveOppertunityEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/FiveOppertunitiesModel.csdl|res://*/FiveOppertunitiesModel.ssdl|res://*/FiveOppertunitiesModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-1LO62C0;initial catalog=FiveOppertunity;User ID=sa;Password=sql@2016;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Answer (score 0):

Both error message point same thing that application can't login to db server.

In model first approach the default connection string name is *DefaultConnection* so when you provide different name then you need to tell EF that you have override that thing. So in your dbconnext you need to do following

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
   public ApplicationDbContext ()
           :base("FiveOppertunityEntities")
   {
   }
}
```

After that also verify if you can actually connect to your **data source** using login credentials placed in your connection string i.e. ***sa*** and ***sql@2016***. If you can login from Management Studio then application should run normally.

Comment: and in DB first Approach what i do in which this send underlying exception

Comment: In DB first approach too there is DbContext file you need to change on that. Same concept applies.

Comment: it's not work in model first approach i try this, and in db first approach i use if (!Database.Exists())
            {
                Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<FiveOppertunityRegistrationEntity>());
                //Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<FiveOppertunityRegistraionEntities1, System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Configuration>());
            } i use this then it start works.